# Multiple domain names and 1 database

Tags: database

What I want is to have a couple of domains having the info from 1 database, this would be nice, because I don't need to edit all websites databases. Is this possible without having problems in the future?

The servers are shared and the host is not local, but I can give a http path to a server.

like: **sql12.backbone.tiscomhosting.nl**

There is only one user, this will be me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to make sure that you're not violating the terms of service with the company who is hosting your database. Having many outside domains hitting an inside database may cause some undue stress on that server that the company is not counting on or eatting up more bandwidth that is aloted for that machine.

In the same breath though, if you setup sometype of datalayered webservice which you can connect to, then your many other domains are not directly hitting the database and do esentially the same thing, but in a more ordered fashion of predictible database calls. This may not be what you're looking for, but if setup correctly it could make developing against your database much easier.

Good luck, and hope this helps some.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to have hundreds of different websites all pointing to one database. You just need to make sure your host will allow your different domains/sites to connect to the same database. After all it's not the domain name that allows communication between the web and data tiers, it's the hosts server configuration and policies.

For example I host one website, but have been thru 2 or 3 different domain names over the past few years. All of the domains point to the same website inside of IIS. Or in the case of one sub-domain points to a different website inside IIS, but still talks to the same database. It's al in your connection strings.

However you will most likely not be able to have the database server on one host, and sites on a different host. These ports are normally shut down for standard communuication.

Your best bet would be to talk to their technical support to see if it's allowed.